# How to make ''string in list'' case-insensitive in python3.8.3

Tags: python

```
print("Say hello in one of these 3 langauges:"+" Hello","Namaste","Salve.")
hello=input()
Language=["English. hello","Hindi. Namaste","Latin. Salve"]
res= [i for i in Language if hello in i]
print(hello+" is hello in"+res)
```

this code only works when I type in a capital letter but not a lowercase letter.Please help me
capfold and capupper do not work

Comment: What is it supposed to do when you input what exactly? Where and how did you use capfold and capupper?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare them after you convert both sides of the condition to lower case.

```py
print("Say hello in one of these 3 languages: " + "Hello", "Namaste", "Salve.")

hello = input()
Language = [ "English. hello", "Hindi. Namaste", "Latin. Salve"]

res = [i for i in Language if hello.lower() in i.lower()]

print(hello + " is hello in" + str(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```
print("Say hello in one of these 3 langauges:"+" Hello","Namaste","Salve.")
hello = input()
Language = ["English. hello","Hindi. Namaste","Latin. Salve"]
res = [i for i in Language if hello.lower() in i.lower()][0]
print(hello.capitalize() + " is hello in " + res.split(".")[0].capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [casefold()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-06uQtubpAhXIWM0KHYU-AC8QFjABegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.programiz.com%2Fpython-programming%2Fmethods%2Fstring%2Fcasefold&usg=AOvVaw1YKeEPilN51y4iLoZdc7UV) method:

```
print("Say hello in one of these 3 langauges: Hello, Namaste, Salve.")
hello=input()
Language=["English. hello","Hindi. Namaste","Latin. Salve"]
for h in Language:
    if hello.casefold() in h.casefold():
        print(f"{hello.title()} is hello in {h.split('.',1)[0]}.")
```

Output:

```
Say hello in one of these 3 langauges: Hello, Namaste, Salve.
salve
Salve is hello in Latin.
```

`string.casefold()` will make it so that we won't have to worry about what case the letters are in.